Water heater thermostat melted
I have a two element, two control, electric water heater and on Friday it stopped working but was easily fixed by hitting the reset button.  Monday we had hurricane Debby come through and lost power for about 30 minutes (including to our well, but the inside bladder should have still been quite full).  On Tuesday I smelled burnt metal in the garage and found that the bottom control and wires were melted.  I replaced the top element and control last year.  Any ideas as to why/how this happened?  Obviously I plan to replace the bottom control...should I replace the element as well if it hasn't "popped"?  I am just concerned if there is a bigger issue that could cause a fire and wondering if I should just replace the entire 12 year old water heater.

Usually burnt/melted stuff at a connection is caused by loose and/or dirty connection.  It causes high resistance(like a heater/burner on a stove).  After the storm, there is a possibility that it got wet also and shorted.

Pull the element out and take a look.  If it looks the least bit suspect, replace it and the control. Be sure the wires are clean aslo.   The tank could need flushing as well.

Checking or replacing the anoid rod can lengthen the replacement time of the tank.  The rod helps prevent the tank from rusting out.
